# PlayConsole pre-launch error "Native crash of /vendor/bin/adsprpcd" due to failed integrity check for appVerdict

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm releasing an internal test for my Android App via PlayConsole.

The pre-launch report noted an issue with the error "Native crash of /vendor/bin/adsprpcd".

Seeing the related test video of that error in PlayConsole, I noticed a my own toast saying that the integrity check had failed while validating the appVerdict.

In detail, my server-side implementation recognized that the appVerdict result was not PLAY_RECOGNIZED.

My App is already online in the production channel, with the integrity check working properly, tested for few months, so I can say that it works. Also, this version is still online and the integrity works fine.
This server-side implementation is exactly the same for those two versions.

I already read other similar question on SO but I need a precise answer about this case.

Does anyone know why and how to make the pre-launch check handle the integrity check correctly?

### Edit & solution that worked for me:

In the pre-launch report this error also occurred:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{myApp}: java.lang.SecurityException: Caller myApp needs
> to hold android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM or
> android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM to set exact alarms.

In the manifest I only had this:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
```

After modifying it this way and uploading a new version to PlayConsole, the error no longer occurs:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" 
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

It may be that the two errors were not related, but in this way the pre-launch result was without any problems.